# How can someone determine if the purchase is on the open market from sec.gov filings?

Tags: stocks, sec

There are sites on the web that show if someone purchased shares of a company when they are an officer, director or 10% shareholder on the open market. I understand that open market shares are non-Derivative, but can you determine if the shares are purchased on the open market from sec.gov filings?

Filings list:
https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/current?q1=0&q2=6&q3=4

Example XML Filing Doc (not sure if this one is open market):
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/815094/000117911017011393/edgar.xml

Answer (score 1):

On the filings there is a transaction code.
3. Transaction Code (Instr. 8)
P — Open market or private purchase of non-derivative or derivative security.